# Seeking .NET opensource library for geometry operations

Tags: software-recommendations, open-source-gis, .net

Are there any opensource librarys for doing geometry operations (union, intersect, relation...) in .NET?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe that [NTS, The .NET Topology Suite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nts/) contains code capable of doing geometry operations on GIS structures.  It's a .NET port of [JTS](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/main.htm).

Answer (score 6):

you might try [SharpMap](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/), or more specificially, the [Net Topology Suite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nts/), which is the .net port of the JTS (java topology suite).

Answer (score 5):

Also checkout [DotSpatial](http://dotspatial.codeplex.com)

http://dotspatial.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=IGeometry&referringTitle=NTSCompare

Answer (score 2):

See MapWindow : [www.mapwindow.org](http://www.mapwindow.org)

Answer (score 1):

Clipper from Angus Johnson:
http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php
http://sourceforge.net/projects/polyclipping/files/

Same library is available as both C#, C++ and Delphi source code.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try out [Topology Framework .NET (TF.NET)](http://code.google.com/p/tf-net/) - an open source topology manipulation API capable of handling managed objects representation of topological entities based on other popular APIs, exposing it's JTS-based common topology manipulation core to them.

[JTS Topology Suite](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/JTSHome.htm) is, in fact, Java API providing spatial object model and fundamental geometric functions, providing a complete, consistent, robust implementation of fundamental 2D spatial algorithms. It implements geometry model defined in the OpenGIS Consortium Simple Features Specification for SQL. JTS port for .NET was named [Net Topology Suite (NTS)](http://nts.sourceforge.net/), and is fully conformant to Microsoft .NET 2.0 specification. NTS extends JTS with numerous coordinate transformation and other functions, while TF.NET extends NTS further, including additional Autodesk and Oracle IO functions and generic classes related to geometry graphs.

More details on TF.NET at [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/tf-net/) and [GitHub](https://github.com/SesticM/tf-net).

Answer (score 0):

Another option I haven't seen on here is [Gmap.NET](https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/) (Great Maps).  The current version is from April 2015.  I haven't personally used it much past creating a layer and viewing it in a WPF application, but it looks like it has great potential.