# Are there any decent free GIS projects built in C# or with a good C# API?

Tags: c#, open-source-gis

I'm looking for a free mapping / gis project with a **C#** interface, preferably written in **C#** and open source. Does such a project exist?

If so, are there any that do not require connecting to a map server and will allow me to distribute map tiles on disc?

Comment: Is MapWindow a C# or .NET open source GIS? http://www.mapwindow.org/apps/wiki/doku.php?id=sourcecode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Dotspatial, SharpMap and NetTopologySuite](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2740/are-there-any-net-opensource-library-for-geometry-operations) are all built in C#.  I'm not totally sure about the map tiles functionality but SharpMap might do this, otherwise you could just use GDAL for this...

Answer (score 0):

See : MapWindow GIS : [www.mapwindow.org](http://www.mapwindow.org)